# git rebase says nothing to do

Tags: git, rebase

I have the following commits, and master and 2 other branches (b1 and b2):

```
m1 - a1 - b1
^    ^    ^ 
|    |    branch b
|    branch a
master
```

I want to rebase b branch so its parent is master:

```
 / - a1
m1
 \ - b1
```

If I do `git rebase master` or `git rebase origin/master`, I get `Current branch b is up to date`. That seems wrong but I think it is related to the fact that b in some ways is already rooted on master. It also seems wrong that I would have to use the --onto.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly in this case you could just cherry-pick the `b1` commit onto a new branch coming from `master`:

```
# from b
git reset --hard master
git cherry-pick b1
```

If you wanted to use a rebase option, then use `--onto`:

```
# from b
git rebase --onto m1 a1
```

The above says to rebase the `b` branch such that the commit whose parent is the `a1` commit (just the `b1` commit) should now sit on a *new* base, specifically commit `m1`.

Answer (score 0):

So not long after I posted this I understood the problem: the command

```
git rebase master
```

takes all the commits from the current branch, all the way back until the first commit that branches from 2nd argument ie `master`, and rebases them onto `master` HEAD.

To clarify why this didn't work, let's add more commits to my original diagram:

```
                      /- b1 - b2
            /- a1 - a2
m1 - m2 - m3
```

where commits that start with "m" are on `master` branch (so `master` HEAD is at `m3`), those starting with "a" are on the `a` branch (so `a` HEAD is commit `a2`), and similarly for "b" (so `b` HEAD is `b2`). My goal was to end up with this:

```
            /- a1 - a2
m1 - m2 - m3
            \- b1 - b2
```

and the commands I tried are basically equivalent to

```
git pull
git checkout b
git rebase master
```

Problem is that "until the first commit that branches from `master`" includes the commits on branch `a`, so git will try to rebase `a1 - a2 - b1 - b2` onto HEAD of `master` which is `m3`. This sequence of commits is already rooted at `m3`, so git says correctly that there is nothing to do.

I had to do instead `git rebase --onto master a` which means "rebase current branch (which is `b`) onto `master`, but only after the HEAD commit of branch `a`", ie "rebase `b1 - b2` onto `m3`".

Comment: This is not a very good explanation. It suffers from the same issue as the question, namely, a misconception as to what a branch is. And the solution is no different from what you had already been told in a much better answer.

Comment: @matt You are right, I completely rewrote it, I hope this is better.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in a single shot like this:

```
git rebase --onto master a b
```

You are telling to rebase on top of master all revisions that make up branch b but discarding revisions that are part of the history of a... in other words, *bring over revision b1 on top of master (creating b1'), set b to point to b1'*.